# jQuery and returned HTML

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

This is probably a no-brainer but I'm stuck.

I've a function which creates a table:

```
function getTable(someJSON, someGroup){
  var table = $("<table>").attr("class", "someTable");
  var row1 = $("<tr>");
  var cell1 = $("<td>").text(someJSON.someThing);
  row1.append(cell1);
  var cell2 = $("<td>").text(someJSON.someThingElse);
  row1.append(cell2);
  var row2 = $("<tr>");
  row2.append("<td>Something</td><td>Something else</td>");
  table.append(row2);
  var row3 = $("<tr>").append(getRow(someJSON, someGroup));
  table.append(row3);
  return table;
}
```

The table is returned okay but there's nothing in the last row.

getRow is like this:

```
function getRow(someJSON, someGroup){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'getRow.php',
    data: ({
      DM: JSON.stringify(someJSON),
      someGroup: someGroup
    }),
    async: false
  })
}
```

I've checked with FireBug and the getRow.php returns a valid result like: 123234 after doing it's thing but I'll be blown if I can get it into the ... I've been thrashing around with it and in an earlier iteration I had something like [object Object] appended to the row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Dom

Comment: I'm in doubt if the 'async: false' option you are providing will actually return the result of the request. I should add a success callback and fill the row when the request is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getRow` does not return anything - that's why your last row is empty :)

But even after you'll fix it - you append it to the TR without a TD inside, so it will not appear in the right place on the screen

Comment: Sorry, my formatting foo isn't up to scratch. the getRow.php returns: < td >123< /td > < td >234< /td >

Answer (score 0):

Don-Joy was right but I miss-read his answer, I've altered getRow to:

```
function getRow(someJSON, someGroup){
  var returnedText;
  $.ajax({
    url: 'getRow.php',
    data: ({
      DM: JSON.stringify(someJSON),
      someGroup: someGroup
    }),
    dataType: "html",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
      returnedText = data;
    }
  });
  return returnedText;
}
```

works a treat now. Thanks for the pointer Don-Joy!

Cheers,

Dom

Answer (score 0):

As Don-Joy say, your **JavaScript function** `getRow` isn't returning anything. It doesn't have a `return` statement. You'll need to change it to:

```
function getRow(someJSON, someGroup){
  var a = $.ajax({
    url: 'getRow.php',
    data: ({
      DM: JSON.stringify(someJSON),
      someGroup: someGroup
    }),
    async: false
  });
  return a.responseText;
}
```

However you should **never** use synchronized AJAX calls like this. It slows down your page considerably and can even make the browser unresponsive.

Comment: As a thumb rule - yes. However, you might consider to use it if you relay on fast connections, highly available CDNs and a fast server reply.